# Does anyone know where a parquet table stores the files?

Tags: hdfs, parquet, hue

I'm inserting some records into a Hive Parquet table and everything is flawlessly working, however I would like to check the files using the hue file browser, does anyone know where are those files located ? and is there a property I could use while creating the table to change the location ?

Here's my table definition:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_test_2 (
column1 int,
column2 int
)
STORED AS PARQUET
TBLPROPERTIES ('PARQUET.COMPRESS'='SNAPPY');
```

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE parquet_test_2` => under LOCATION

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT Input__File__Name FROM parquet_test_2` to get the list of each and every data file created in that LOCATION *(for a partitioned table there would be sub-dirs...)*

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - full table scan in order to get the files names is not something I would recommend (Theoretically it can be optimized, but this is not the case).

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz, I strongly believe that some people must get *burnt* to learn a lesson...

Answer (score 0):

You should have control over the directory where you are writing files. I am writing data from once hive to another but I change the format from text to parquet and I am using below command:

```
val hiveDF = hsc.sql(iSql)
hiveDF.coalesce(noExecutors).write.mode("append").parquet(parquetLoc)`
```

It would be similar if you are writing from a plain text file. As @Samson Scharfrichter mentioned you can use the `LOCATION` option while creating the table to have specific directory as your source but you need to make sure you are writing data to that directory only.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_test_2 (
column1 int,
column2 int
)
STORED AS PARQUET 
LOCATION '{HDFS_DIR}'
TBLPROPERTIES ('PARQUET.COMPRESS'='SNAPPY');
```

Answer (score 0):

1.
The location of the table is under the location of the database you are using to store the table.
If you are not explicitly defining a database (`create my_database.mytable ...`) than it is your current active database (by default it is `default` and it can be changed using `use mydatabase;`)
The location of the database can be found using `desc database my_database;`

2.
I strongly recommend to treat Hive as a data warehouse and not as temp directory on one's personal computer.
The data should be organized using databases and not by determine each table's location separately.

#### Demo

```
create database prod;    
desc database prod;
```

---

```
+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
| db_name | comment |                          location                           | owner_name | owner_type | parameters |
+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
| prod    |         | hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/prod.db | hive       | USER       |            |
+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

---

```
use prod;
create table my_prod_table as select 'This is a PROD table';    
show table extended in prod like my_prod_table;
```

---

```
...
location:hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/prod.db/my_prod_table
...
```

---

```
create database playground location '/tmp/my_hive_playground'; 
desc database playground;
```

---

```
+------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  db_name   | comment |                        location                        | owner_name | owner_type | parameters |
+------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
| playground |         | hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/my_hive_playground | hive       | USER       |            |
+------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

---

```
create table playground.my_playground_table as select 'This is a Playground table';    
show table extended in playground like my_playground_table
```

---

```
...
location:hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/tmp/my_hive_playground/my_playground_table
...
```